# How to 'accurev diff' a kept new file?

Tags: accurev

I created a new file with content in my workspace, and then I 'accurev add' it. So the current state of this file in my stream is '(kept) (member)'.

However I found I cannot 'accurev diff' it. For example, if you I 'accurev diff -k -b', accurev only reports 
  No element named

Any hints?

Comment: I think 'accurev diff -k -b' does correct (from AccuRev point of view), but useless thing. I believe that much more useful behavior is just to add whole new file in the diff output and optionally dump a warning (e.g. "Only in workspace stream"). That's probably what most users expect to see.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand what accurev diff is doing.  There are options to diff a file under AccuRev's control against the most recent kept version, the version in the backing stream, or any other version.

In your case, since you just added the file to AccuRev, it's the first real version of the file.  There's nothing to diff it against.  If you were to make more modifications to that file but nothing else, you could diff against most recent, and it would compare your mods against the version you initially added.  If you then keep and promote that file, it exists in the parent (backing stream) now.  If you make more local mods, and diff against backed, you can see the local workspace changes against what is in the parent stream.

Hope this answers the question...
Cheers,
~James